# MUI styled component and TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, styled-components

I have the following codes

```
import {Button,ButtonProps} from '@mui/material';
import { alpha, styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { Link as RouterLink } from 'react-router-dom';

const BackButton = styled(Button)<ButtonProps>(({ theme }) => ({
  borderColor: alpha(theme.palette.text.primary, 0.5),
  padding: theme.spacing(1),
}));
```

and

```
  const backButton = (
    <BackButton
      to={'/my/path'}
      component={RouterLink}
      fullWidth
      variant="outlined"
      color="inherit"
    >
      Back
    </BackButton>
  );
```

I have a typescript error for `to` props, How can I fix it?

```
TS2322: Type '{ children: string; to: string; component: typeof Link; fullWidth: true; variant: "outlined"; color: "inherit"; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; classes?: Partial<ButtonClasses>; color?: "inherit" | "error" | "primary" | "secondary" | "success" | "info" | "warning"; ... 9 more ...; variant?: "text" | ... 1 more ... | "contained"; } & ... 4 more ... & { ...; }'.   Property 'to' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; classes?: Partial<ButtonClasses>; color?: "inherit" | "error" | "primary" | "secondary" | "success" | "info" | "warning"; ... 9 more ...; variant?: "text" | ... 1 more ... | "contained"; } & ... 4 more ... & { ...; }'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [components complications section on the MUI Typescript page](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/typescript/#complications-with-the-component-prop).

Modify your styled component to add a type conversion at the end:

```js
const BackButton = styled(Button)(({ theme }) => ({
  borderColor: alpha(theme.palette.text.primary, 0.5),
  padding: theme.spacing(1),
})) as typeof Button;
```

Comment: This does not work anymore in newer versions: `Conversion of type ... may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other.`

Answer (score -1):

Try adding an onClick handler to the button to handle the redirect:

```
const handleClick = () => {
   navigate('/my/path')
}

const backButton = (
    <BackButton
      onClick={handleClick}
      component={RouterLink}
      fullWidth
      variant="outlined"
      color="inherit"
    >
      Back
    </BackButton>
  );
```